# Is there a principle for the word order of idioms e.g. Town & Gown rather than Gown & Town?

Tags: expressions

The second version sounds awkward but I don't know why?

So is there any rule for these idioms e.g. reverse alphabetical order e.g. Walkie Talkie?

Is there a name for these?

Just found another Sooner or Later

Comment: With 'Hell-Volhard-Zelinsky', 'hot and bothered' and 'cranny and nook', I'd argue that the alternatives were non-starters. Here, it may well be just the way it caught on.

Comment: Not to say that you are playing "fast and loose" with your examples or comparing "apples and oranges," but I don't think that paired idioms in which the terms appear in reverse alphabetical order are (in terms of frequency) "head and shoulders" above paired idioms whose terms appear in alphabetical order. The order seems pretty random to me.

Answer (score 1):

Speculative answer (with references and support where available):

The reason behind why some phrases, titles, terms, idioms, etc., sound better one way than the other are because of a number of reasons. This take place in a logical order.

1. Leading sounds (vowel sounds in this order O U A E I, then the opposite way for consonants -- words that have 'softer' sounds dominating over words that are harder, e.g., 'T' and 'B' before 'G' and 'V')
2. Amount of syllables (words with fewer syllables usually take precedence over words with longer ones)
3. Reverse order of the English alphabet (something to do with reading backwards always makes us retain things better). [Example](http://randallweiss.wordpress.com/2011/01/14/editing-do-it-backwards/), [example 2](http://writingcenter.unc.edu/handouts/editing-and-proofreading/)

Some examples:

- **Tom & Jerry:** shorter word (1 syllable) comes first.
- **Sharky & George:** ShArky -- combination of softer 'Sh' sound vs strong 'Je' (George) sound. Also 'A' comes before the 'E' phoneme. Combination of 'ShA-r-KEY' takes precedence over the stronger 'GeoRge'. Also, alphabetical order. From Z to A. S comes before G.
- **This & That**: Reverse alphabetical order. From Z to A, I comes before A.

Comment: The "reverse alphabetical order" idea seems a bit arbitrary, and the links you give don't really support that claim at all.

Comment: @starwed That's why I said it was speculative. I will go into further if required, but since the question is now on hold, I don't see a reason to.

Comment: Sure, but from skimming it I assumed your links actually supported what you said -- when I actually read them I was a bit surprised.

Comment: @starwed I was trying to find something that wasn't too technical. I really didn't want to get into word order, typology, and morphology, all of which would apply to this question.

Comment: To me, _George & Sharky_ actually sounds a lot better than _Sharky & George_. But I’m quite unbiased by previous experience, since I’ve never heard of them before (I assume they’re another cartoon duo or similar). Apart from the number of syllables in each word having some limited influence on the order of words, I sincerely doubt anything in this answer truly makes much of a difference. ‘Bacon and eggs’, for example, simultaneously breaks all three ‘rules’.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I think it's simply a matter of having heard one version more often than the other. Idiom, not linguistics.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the sound?  Or the manner in which you need to use your tongue to pronounce the letter 'T'.  Having the tip of your tongue pressed against the top of your mouth and right behind the front tooth is in itself awkward.  Whereas, [most children have mastered the /k/ and /g/ sounds by about 3 1/2 years of age.](http://mommyspeechtherapy.com/?p=42)

Comment: The transition from the D to the T is probably a bit unwieldy, too.